# Generating function in action-angle method and Hamilton-Jacobi theory

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

I think that in action angle method, generating function which generates such a canonical transformation does not explicitly depend on time, so new and old hamiltonians are equal. But in H-J method, generating functions are explicitly dependent upon time. Can some one please clarify this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems OP is essentially talking about the difference between

1. [Hamilton's principal function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation#Mathematical_formulation) $S(q,\alpha,t)$ and
2. [Hamilton's characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation#Separation_of_variables) $W(q,\alpha)$ for time-independent systems.

Comment: so Hamilton's characteristic function generates new hamiltonian in action angle theory, am I right ??